# JX Promote returns 404 and exits from the job

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, google-kubernetes-engine, jenkins-x

#### Summary

jx installed in GKE(Google Kubernetes engine) and configured bitbucket cloud repository.

When trying to promote the build using jx promote returns

```
Promoting app sample-spring version 0.0.11 to namespace jx-staging

error: finding existing PRs using filter  on repo baskar030/environment-XXX-staging: listing open pull requests on baskar030/environment-XXX-staging: Status: 404 Not Found, Body: {"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Resource not found", "detail": "There is no API hosted at this URL.\n\nFor information about our API's, please refer to the documentation at: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/"}}

script returned exit code 1
```

#### Jx version

The output of `jx version` is:

```
COPY OUTPUT HERE
NAME               VERSION
jx                 2.0.398
jenkins x platform 2.0.744
Kubernetes cluster v1.12.8-gke.10
kubectl            v1.12.8-dispatcher
helm client        Client: v2.13.1+g618447c
git                git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)
Operating System   Mac OS X 10.13.6 build 17G65
```

#### Jenkins type

- Classic Jenkins

#### Kubernetes cluster

GKE Cluster  version 1.12.8-gke.10

#### Operating system / Environment

Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to this issue: [Bitbucket Cloud API deprecations](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/2149)

As long as [the bitbucket cloud API](https://github.com/wbrefvem/go-bitbucket) used by Jenkins X (See jx\pkg\gits\bitbucket_cloud.go) hasn't been fixed, you'll run into this error.